# Apache as reverse proxy doesn't work

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I am trying to publish, behind a proxy, a Spring app (also with Spring Security) which has /x/services as entry point. It is running in Tomcat in 8080 in Google Engine (Debian). I configure Apache 2 as a reverse proxy with next configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ProxyRequests off
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
        # Servers to proxy the connection, or
        # List of application servers Usage
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/x/services/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/x/services
        ServerName localizator.org
        ServerAlias *.localizator.org
</VirtualHost>
```

I checked it against a lot of examples and seems it is OK, but the only response I am getting is the "Index of /" page. And Apache logs are not helping at all.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you hit Tomcat directly (i.e. `http://hostname.tld:8080/x/services/`)? In other words, is it Tomcat or the proxy that is the issue?

Comment: Tomcat is working fine, is the connection between the proxy and Tomcat which is failing. The "Index of /" page, should means Apache isn't working as a proxy, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct as Tomcat isn't serving `/`.  I'm still a bit confused as, except for the `<Proxy>` stanza I have almost the exact same setup with no issues.  As an aside, somewhere you've got `Options +Indexes` enabled in Apache and likely don't want.  But otherwise I'm afraid I'm not sure.

Comment: Please, add the solution as your own answer. You will be able to accept it after 2 days or so. That's the way to go on SO, not editing the title by adding Solved.

Comment: Foolishly, seems as I forgot to issue the configuration last but not least command (my .conf file name is proxy-host):

sudo a2ensite proxy-host
I hope at least this can be useful for other people who need to set up a reverse proxy for first time. Any case, thanks stdunbar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with a similar problem don't forget to do :

```
sudo a2ensite proxy-host
```

(lets suppose your .conf file name is proxy-host)